# Word count is greater than what was supposed to be wrriten to a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

The csv file I am working with has `9,174,189` lines. My poor mom was trying to go through the file manually and delete what she didn't need in excel. There are `256098` rows that meet her criterion. However, whenever I write the rows to a new csv file a line count on this file returns `269100` lines. This does not make any sense. The length of the generator object is `256098`. Why are there more lines being written to the new csv file than the length of the generator object?

Here is a link to the [csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H5ZFhijKeOfpriZYsIJc5txUkA6yTy8s/edit) file. This is all public information btw.

To be clear, I am using `wc -l new.csv` to get the line count and opening the file in vim
shows that there are `269100` lines. I am also using python version `3.6.9` if that matters. Below is my cvs reader and writer.

```
import csv, os

def getstuff(filename,keywords,field):

    with open(filename, "r") as csvfile:

        datareader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        yield datareader.fieldnames

        for row in datareader:

            for k in keywords:
                if k in row[field]
                    yield row
                    break # row[field] might contain multiple keywords


def writestuff(gen,fileout):

    with open(fileout, "w") as csvfile:

        datawriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames=next(gen))
        datawriter.writeheader()
        datawriter.writerows(gen)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    k1 = ["Staff","Aug"]
    f1 = "RFO Description"

    files = os.listdir()
    filename = files[0]

    x = getstuff(filename,k1,f1)
    writestuff(x,"new.csv")
```

I have verified that there are `256098` rows that meet her criterion with this function.

```
def f(filename,field):

    d = {}

    with open(filename, "r") as csvfile:
        datareader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in datareader:
            try:
                d[row[field]] += 1
            except KeyError:
                d[row[field]] = 1
    return d
```

I have been writing the dictionary produced by this function to a file called `file.txt`. When I pass `new.csv` and `k1` to this function and `cat file.txt` I get the following:

```
Augmenting Software Products and Services,20285
Augmenting Networking Equipment,2323
Information Technology Staff Augmentation Contract (ITSAC) Services,1752
Information Technology Staff Augmentation Contract (ITSAC),212324
Deliverables-Based Information Technology Services (DBITS) - Augmenting,7947
Augmenting Hardware, Software, and Related Services for Surveillance, Security and Monitoring,9985
Software Solutions - Augmenting DIR-TSO-TMP-416,1482
```

The values in this dictionary do indeed sum to `256098`. If I instead pass the original file, to
`f` and run `cat file.txt | grep 'Aug'` I get the exact same output("Staff" does not occur anywhere else). I don't think there is anything wrong with the csv file because when I read the entire file into a generator and then write the generator to another csv file I get all `9` million lines.

Furthmore, changing `datawriter.writerows(gen)` to

```
counter = 0
for g in gen
    counter +=1
    datawriter.writerow(g)
```

shows that `datawriter.writerow(g)` is only being called `256098` times. Finally, changing the dialect and including `newline=''` as parameter in `open()` does not help.

Comment: Its possible that some cells have an embedded newline. e.g., `"foo\nbar"` in quotes so that the newline isn't a row separator. You could do a simple `table = list(csv.reader(open("filename", newline="")))` and then see if table is the correct length.

Comment: @tdelaney I don't think my computer is capable of such a feat. After a while python exits and the word Killed is printed

Comment: Try `print(sum(1 for _ in csv.reader(open("filename", newline=""))))`. Or you could do something like your original code where you go row by row, testing each column to see if a newline is in it.

Comment: .... and do it to the smaller written CSV that has the odd line count.

Comment: you are right about there being newlines because your suggestion yielded 9005190

Comment: I hope that means all is well and mom is happy.

Comment: Yes, I was able to add a simple filter to `getstuff`. Thank you. Are the rogue `\n`s necessarily in quotes? If the document just had `foo\nbar` wouldn't I still run into the same issue assuming that `foo` and `bar` were meant to be a part of the same row?

Comment: CSV is somewhat vaguely defined and not all parsers work alike, but as far as I know, the only way to escape the newline in the python csv parser is with quotes. `foo\nbar` is two rows definitionally with CSV, whatever the intent. Some other mechanism like a backslash just before the newline would likely not be generally acceptable to CSV parsers.